# How to add css with the associated span on checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the class to the associated span on checkbox checked with the following code. actually I wants to add the "text-decoration-line", "line-through" to the associated the checkbox span.

But now when I am click on first checkbox css applies to all spans as shown in code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(".label-text").css("text-decoration-line", "line-through");
    } else {
      $(".label-text").css("text-decoration-line", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-3 bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
    <span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
    <span class="label-text">Set due date and assignments</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
    <span class="label-text">Remove duplicate tasks and stories</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
    <span class="label-text">Update the userflow and stories</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
    <span class="label-text">Adjust the components</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more details like What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: updated please check

Comment: I have added a solution for this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next element, the issue was that you are doing a select on class which apply the CSS on all elements, here is how you can do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    $(this).next().css("text-decoration-line", this.checked ? "line-through" : "none" );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-3 bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Set due date and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Remove duplicate tasks and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Update the userflow and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Adjust the components</span></label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

because you set all `.label-text`.  you should set one which is next input

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
   
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).next(".label-text").css("text-decoration-line", "line-through");
    } else {
       $(this).next(".label-text").css("text-decoration-line", "none");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-3 bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Set due date and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Remove duplicate tasks and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Update the userflow and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Adjust the components</span></label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now `$(".label-text")` is going to select every element that matches that class. So when `this.checked` is true, all checkboxes will be updated.

Instead, try using [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) along with [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parent().find(".label-text").css("text-decoration-line", "line-through");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find(".label-text").css("text-decoration-line", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-3 bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Set due date and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Remove duplicate tasks and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Update the userflow and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Adjust the components</span></label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="p-3 bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span> Set due date and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span> Remove duplicate tasks and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span> Update the userflow and stories</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span> Adjust the components</span></label></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if (this.checked) {
          $this.next('span').css('text-decoration-line','line-through');
        } else {
          console.log('un-clicked');
          $this.next('span').css("text-decoration-line", "none");
        }
   });
});
```

You have to add `<span>` tag to each text or sentence to apply class or css.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some minor modification in html. So as per my assumption modified as below,

HTML:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).next().addClass( "yourClass" ) // I assume you wanted to add class to text element 
            $(this).next().css("text-decoration-line", "line-through");// I assume you wanted to strike out the text on clicking checkboxes 

        } else {
            $(this).next().removeClass( "yourClass" )
            $(this).next().css("text-decoration-line", "none");
        }

    });
    });
```

```css
.yourclass{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="p-3 bg-white">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
            <span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span>
        </label>
        </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
            <span>&nbsp;Set due date and assignments<span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
            <span>&nbsp;Remove duplicate tasks and stories<span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
            <span>&nbsp;Update the userflow and stories<span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">
            <span>&nbsp;Adjust the components<span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).next().addClass( "yourClass" ) // I assume you wanted to add class to text element 
        $(this).next().css("text-decoration-line", "line-through");// I assume you wanted to strike out the text on clicking checkboxes 

    } else {
        $(this).next().removeClass( "yourClass" )
        $(this).next().css("text-decoration-line", "none");
    }

});
});
```

Comment: But its unclear where you wanted to add class exactly

Answer (score 0):

Have some feedback on the implementation:

1. It is more manageable to organize style with css class. In this example I create `option-label__checked` to hold the `text-decoration-line` style.
2. We can utilize a technique call event delegation, to have single event handle to serve multiple UI control. Since you use jQuery, the technique is 
   implemnted by [.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)
   . I attach the handle to `.p-3` and listen for `change` event coming from `input` element. It becomes handy when controls are added dynamicly. It also helps performance-wise
3. The reason your sample doesn't work because you apply `line-through` to all `.label-text` at once.
4. [`.toggleClass( className, state )`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-state) second paramter allows you put to a boolean to turn a class on or off, fits perfectly with the checkbox status. And the statement comes in single line.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.p-3').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('option-label__checked', this.checked);

  });

});
```

```css
.option-label__checked {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p-3 bg-white">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio"><span class="label-text">Task list and assignments</span></label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">&nbsp;Set due date and assignments</label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">&nbsp;Remove duplicate tasks and stories</label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">&nbsp;Update the userflow and stories</label></div>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center"><label><input type="checkbox" class="option-input radio">&nbsp;Adjust the components</label></div>
</div>
```